# SQL Server : how to union 3 tables with different number of rows

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables with different data and I need to return one table that includes all 3 tables:

```
Customer
Contacts
Addresses
```

I want to get the data in only one table and one record with all details like CustomerNumber, Name, City, officeNumber...., like Union

```
SELECT CU.[Name] 
FROM Customers CU  
WHERE CustomerNumber = @CustomerId 
  AND IsDeleted = 0

SELECT AD.City, AD.Street 
FROM [Addresses] AD
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId 
  AND IsDeleted = 0

SELECT CO.FullName, CO.OfficeNumber, CO.Email
FROM [Contacts] CO 
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId 
  AND IsDeleted = 0
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need UNION. Just a guess - you are probably looking for JOIN operation across 3 tables. Please update your question with expected result table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of rows doesn't matter for a union  number of columns do.

What do you expect with a union?

I suppose you want you want all information (name  address, contact) of customer having Id= @CustomerId

If I am right, you should make 2 join between the 3 tables using CustomerId as join clause

Edit:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uGhtAZAVk64KzgThGekKk6/11

Comment: Can you helpme and write for me, I am new in SQL. But JOIN get me all rows, I want Only one row with all details like CustomerNumber, Name, City, officeNumber......

Comment: You can't have only one row whereas there are two rows of addresses... What kind of results do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN the tables not UNION them. Please research SQL Server JOIN as there multiple types of joins you can do. In this case you're looking for an INNER JOIN this type of join will only return records when you have matching keys in all the tables. The key in your case is the customer id. You JOIN the tables ON customer id. Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT CU.[Name], AD.City, AD.Street, CO.FullName, CO.OfficeNumber, CO.Email
FROM Customers CU 
INNER JOIN [Addresses] AD
ON CU.CustomerNumber = AD.CustomerId 
INNER JOIN [Contacts] CO
ON CO.CustomerId = CU.CustomerNumber
WHERE CU.CustomerNumber = @CustomerId
```